# How can I target a sibling element that is not of the same type?

Tags: jquery, parent, siblings

I want all links with class `play` to show the one and only video element present in their container.

The simplified HTML looks like this:

```
<div>
    <a class="play">Play</a>
    <video>…</video>
</div>
```

And I'm thinking along these lines for the jQuery, but don't understand how to target an element inside of parent:

```
$('.play').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var target = $(this).parent().$('video');
    t.show();
})
```

Comment: Don't put the `.` in `class=".play"`, it should just be `class="play"`.

Comment: Oops, that was a slip up. Not in the actual HTML, but thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
$(this).parent().find('video:first');
```

OR

```
$(this).siblings('video');
```

BTW, your HTML is incorrect, it should be:

```
<a class="play">Play</a> <!-- no need for '.' before the class attribute value -->
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [.find](http://api.jquery.com/find/):

```
$(this).parent().find("video");
```

Or [.siblings](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/):

```
$(this).siblings("video");
```